# Refreshing values in Attribute table automatically after they were changed in database

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, update

I've connected QGIS to an external database, which records the entry and exit of vehicles in a car park.The objective is to follow the entries and exits of vehicles in real time. However, the attribute table in which the data is recorded in QGIS does not update automatically. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need a trigger for your layers and use the notify notification in QGIS. https://kartoza.com/en/blog/using-pgnotify-to-automatically-refresh-layers-in-qgis/